# AngularJS ngRepeat replacing bindings with nothing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an AngularJS app that is searching through a list of services, which then displays the results below the search bar using ngRepeat. The right amount of search results are being displayed, but the bindings are being filled with nothing, leaving the anchor tags empty.

Here is the markup being generated:

```
<h4 class="media-heading result-heading"><a href="#"></a></h4>
<p class="result-abstract"></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-all-12 result-contact">
        <div class="">
            <span class="icon-office"></span>  <a href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <span class="icon-phone"></span>  <a href="#"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have the exact same code running on my local machine, it works as expected, and the versions of AngularJS are the same, so I have no clue what is going on. Has anyone experienced this before, and how have hey resolved it?

No errors are thrown, the data is being retrieved via AJAX from a json file.
Here is the template with the ngRepeats in it:

```
<div class="media-body search-result" ng-repeat="service in services | filter: query | filterTags: allTags | orderBy: serviceOrder:direction | hasValue | startFrom:(currentPage - 1) * servicesPerPage | limitTo:servicesPerPage">
    <h4 class="media-heading result-heading"><a href="#">{{service.serviceName}}</a></h4>
    <p class="result-abstract">{{service.abstract}}</p>
    </p>
    </p>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-all-12 result-contact">
            <div class="">
                <span class="icon-office"></span>  <a href="#">{{service.office}}</a>
            </div>
            <div class="">
                <span class="icon-phone"></span>  <a href="#">{{service.contact}}</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The code behind this isn't really all that important since it is an exact copy of everything from one page to another, and it works on the previous page. There are no differences in the HTML, CSS or Javascript, other than the fact that the markup on the new page is filled in with blanks.
I have already checked to make sure that the json data is being pulled in correctly, and that the versions of AngularJS are the same (Version is 1.2.21).

Here are the custom filters:

```
serviceSearchbar.filter('startFrom', function () {
    return function (input, start) {
        start = +start; //parse to int
        return input.slice(start);
    }
});

serviceSearchbar.filter('hasValue', function() {
    return function (input) {
        if (angular.element('#servicesQuery').val()) {
            return input;
        }
        return [];
    }
});

serviceSearchbar.filter("isSelected", function () {
    return function (input) {
        var response = {};
        if (input !== undefined) {
            Object.keys(input).forEach(function (tag) {
                if (input[tag] !== false) {
                    response[tag] = true;
                }
            });
        }
        return response;
    }
});

serviceSearchbar.filter("filterTags", ["$filter", function ($filter) {
    return function (input, tags) {
        var selectedTags = [],
            response = input,
            found = false,
            numSelectedTags;

        if (input === undefined) {
            return input;
        }


        if (tags !== undefined) {
            Object.keys(tags).forEach(function (tag) {
                if (tags[tag] !== false) {
                    selectedTags.push(tag);
                }
            });
        }

        if (selectedTags.length > 0) {
            response = $filter("filter")(response, function(value) {
                var found = false;
                selectedTags.forEach(function(tag) {
                    if (value.tags.indexOf(tag) !== -1) {
                        found = true;
                        return true;
                    }
                });
                return found;
            });
        }

        return response;
    }
}]);
```

And here is an example of the data that is being used:

```
{
    "services": [
        {
            "serviceName": "Department of Art",
            "sponsor": "Department of Art",
            "shortName": "art-dep",
            "url": "http://www.byui.edu/art/",
            "contactName": "Contact Name",
            "office": "Spori some room",
            "contact": "(123) 456-7890",
            "mapUrl": "http://www.byui.edu/maps#SPO",
            "tags": [
                "art",
                "design",
                "art department",
                "art program"
            ],
            "abstract": "The BYU-Idaho Department of Art provides an aesthetic, conceptual, and technical foundation in the visual arts for students who possess a wide range of interests, experiences, and abilities."
        },
        {
            "serviceName": "College of Performing and Visual Arts",
            "sponsor": "College of Performing and Visual Arts",
            "shortName": "performing-visual-arts",
            "url": "http://www.byui.edu/performing-visual-arts",
            "contactName": "Contact Name",
            "office": "Spori some room",
            "contact": "(123) 456-7890",
            "mapUrl": "http://www.byui.edu/maps#SPO",
            "tags": [
                "art",
                "dance",
                "music",
                "spori",
                "theater"
            ],
            "abstract": "The College of Performing and Visual Arts provide an important means of communication where thoughts, creativity, and expression can be directed to ennoble, uplift, inspire..."
        },
        {
            "serviceName": "Spori Art Gallery",
            "sponsor": "Department of Art",
            "shortName": "spo-gal",
            "url": "http://www.byui.edu/spori-gallery/",
            "contactName": "Contact Name",
            "office": "Spori some room",
            "contact": "(123) 456-7890",
            "mapUrl": "http://www.byui.edu/maps#SPO",
            "tags": [
                "art",
                "gallery",
                "spori"
            ],
            "abstract": "Jacob Spori Art Gallery will show works of current BYU-Idaho Visual Arts students, selected by the art department faculty."
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Do you really think we will guess how your code works/looks like?
Any errors? What bindings are you using, from where are you getting the data? Anything!

Comment: I've added some more info.

Comment: Can you see the data actually come back on Fiddler etc when on the live site? And no errors in the console? Also do you minify your code in production?

Comment: It looks that you have problems with one of the filters. are you able to provide us with sources of custom filters?

Comment: We do minify the code for production, however the current code is not minified. I've been using console.log() to display the code coming back from the AJAX call. There are no errors in the console.

Comment: Also, the data that is returning from the filters is correct. I just did another check, and all of the necessary data is being returned for each result.